Deeplink to Capacitor Electron is opening the wrong Electron App
I have a capacitor-community/electron app on a Mac with deepLinkingEnabled and my own deepLinkingCustomProtocol set. When I use the deeplink to it, it opens this Electron app instead of the one I'm running even if I already have my electron app running.

I've added listeners for 'open-url', 'second-instance', and 'call-open-url' in the index.ts but they don't seem to trigger at all. BrowserWindow.getAllWindows() in index.ts also just returns 1 window and so the two programs are not aware of each other.  What's going on? Why does it think that is the app I want to open?
